# Test individual classes in a Flex Project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to write and test `xmlStuff.as`.  I would like to test it on its own without launching the entire application (launched with index.mxml).

```
Project
    Folder: src
        Package: Default Package
            - index.mxml
        Package: com
            Package: ourCompany
                Package: ourProduct
                    Package: util
                        XmlStuff.as
                    Package: ...
```

If I was using java what I would do is I would create a new package:

```
com.ourCompany.ourProduct.util.test
```

And I would put this code in it:

```
public class xmlStuffTester {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        XmlStuff xs = new XmlStuff();
        // Test methods..
        System.out.println(xs.method1());

    }

}
```

*(Alternatly I would write a unit test if I knew exactly what the xml output should be.  I don't know that yet so I prefer the above approach.)*

**Question:** What is the standard way to do this in Flex builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create unit test for that. Read more info in [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS064a3073e805330f-57274fcd12dfe5a574a-8000.html).

Comment: True, however you need the premium version of Flex to do that.  I just have the standard version.

Comment: In this case you had to create your own test runner and test suites manually. Or you can run test from the command line (using Maven or Ant).